# Animation to ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I have an RotateAnimation with transition of views

```
var i = 0
for (image in imageList) {
     image.translationX = translationsize[i].x
     image.translationY = translationsize[i].x
     val anim = RotateAnimation(
         0f, 360f,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivots[i].x,
         Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivots[i].y
     )
     anim.duration = 1500
     anim.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
     anim.repeatMode = Animation.RESTART
     anim.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
     image.startAnimation(anim)
     i++
}
```

[image: animation]

I want to make the same animation using ObjectAnimator, but it does not work

```
 val pvhX: PropertyValuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_X, 60f)
        val pvhY: PropertyValuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_Y, 60f)
        val rotate: PropertyValuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("rotation", 0f, 360f)
        val animator: ObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(image, pvhX, pvhY, rotate)
        animator.duration = 1500
        animator.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
        animator.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.RESTART
        animator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        animator.start()
```